# Empty Response after Axios Post

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

i have a problem with an axios post. I have a formData who stores the information that i need, but when i do the post, the entry is empty and i dont know why, because i print the formdata previously and it's correct. Thanks everyone

```
const register_formData = new FormData();

const loadData = () => {
register_formData.nombre = nombre;
register_formData.subtitulo = subtitulo;
register_formData.descripcion = descripcion;
register_formData.fecha_inicio = fecha;
register_formData.carga_horaria_hs = carga;
register_formData.profesor = profesor;
register_formData.origen = origen;
register_formData.categoria = null;
console.log(register_formData);
axios
  .post(BASE_URL + "course/", register_formData)
  .then((response) => console.log(response.data));
};
```

Comment: whats the question here? Is the response empty or ```console.log(register_formData);
``` this line is empty?

Comment: the response.data is empty, the console.log(register_formdata) is ok

Comment: can u put the baseurl here?

Comment: and delete / after course in url